# Font weight useless when printing an html web page

Tags: html, css, fonts

I write some html like this:

```
<strong>this is basketball</strong>
<div>this is basketball</div>
<div style="font-weight:700">this is basketball</div>
```

It's working fine on the browser. Like this:

[image]

But if I wanna print the html to a pdf file on chrome, my font weight settings are no longer useful. I get this:

[image]

I get kind of confused. It's an old PC with windows XP. The chrome is also outdated. What should I do to make my font-weights settings printable?

Answer (score 0):

Could potentially use `<b></b>`, not sure if it will work since its applying the style in the same way. But worth a try.